# Updating database after code changes in Entity framework Database First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I had a class named feedback generated via database first approach

```
public partial class Feedback
{
    public Nullable<byte> OverallExperienceFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> FunFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> FoodFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> TravelFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> PlanningFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> MusicFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> PlaceFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<byte> WeatherFb { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Paid { get; set; }
    public int ID{get; set;}
}
```

I later added a constraint of range 0-5 on `overallFb` as following:-

```
public partial class TravellerTripStatus
{
    [Range(0,5)]
    public Nullable<byte> OverallExperienceFb { get; set; }
}
```

This change is reflecting on the GUI such that the edit form won't allow to enter value out of the range but **how to make this change reflect into database** (such that a check contraint automatically gets added to `overallFB` field of table definition)?

When i try to generate database from model, no such constraint is enforced.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server ?

Comment: Its an asp.net application using SQL Server localDB

Answer (score 0):

Adding constraints to a table is currently not possible with data annotations or fluid API. But the workaround is to issue a SQL command in your Configuration.cs file inside your Seed method:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE TravellerTripStatus ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TravellerTripStatus_OverallExperienceFb CHECK (OverallExperienceFb BETWEEN 0 AND 5)");
```

Comment: Basically, i'll have to manually apply the constraint. to the database table. hmmm

Comment: Yes. The one advantage you have in adding the above line to the Configuration file over altering the database directly is that you don't have to remember to do it should you need to re-deploy the system from scratch.